# Flexbox pattern 1/3/3 column and row combo

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get the div 1 to be large and then div 2 and 3 to stack next to it and be equal height as it but it will vary depending on content and then have div 4, 5, 6 be on the next line but equal widths as 2 and 3.

```
------------------
|           |  2  |
|     1     |-----|
|           |  3  |
------------------
|  4  |  5  |  6  |
------------------

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hero">I'm Box 1<br>Some other text
  <br>Some other text
  <br>Some other text
  <br>Some other text</div>
  <div class="hero">Box 2</div>
  <div class="hero">Box 3</div>
  <div class="hero">Box 4</div>
  <div class="hero">Box 5</div>
  <div class="hero">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {

}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;    
}

.d-flex > div {
  margin: 5px;
}

.hero {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #7e58b7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.hero:first-child { flex-basis: calc(66.66% - 10px); }
.hero:nth-child(2),
.hero:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
@media (max-width: 736px) {
  .hero { flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px); }
  .hero:first-child { flex-grow: 1; }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I also have a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/jqc0gkyo/4/

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Do you want box 2 and 3 to be on top of each other?

Comment: Unfortuantely, flexbox is not built to handle how the sizes of elements on one line relate to the sizes of elements on another line - only how the sizes of elements on one line relate to the other elements on the same line.

Comment: Indeed, not possible with flexbox. I'm also not entirely clear what this is supposed to look like.

Comment: Yes box 2 and 3 would be over each other

Comment: I updated in the HTML code a rough layout of what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

For such a layout with flexbox, you need to inbricate your flex boxes, reset some flex value to set the initial area to spray your boxes.

From bootstrap 4 or plain CSS (same classname used) , you may alternate row and columns to lay groups of boxes.

*I added backgrounds gradient and opacity to see your 9 areas where you wished to spray your boxes. notice that it is the initial layout, once filled with content, heights may vary.*

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column
}

.f1 {
  flex: 1.02;
}

.f2 {
  flex: 2;
}

body>.d-flex {
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 90vh;
  /* see areas */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66.66%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66.66%)
}

.d-flex>.hero {
  margin: 10px;
  /* see areas through */
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.hero {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #7e58b7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

body {}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="d-flex f2">
    <div class="hero f2">I'm Box 1<br>Some other text
      <br>Some other text
      <br>Some other text
      <br>Some other text</div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column f1 ">
      <div class="hero f1">Box 2</div>
      <div class="hero f1">Box 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex f1">
    <div class="hero f1">Box 4</div>
    <div class="hero f1">Box 5</div>
    <div class="hero f1">Box 6</div>
  </div>
```

[pen to play with including bootstrap-4 library](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NvwRLP)

Comment: Only issue is was trying not rely on bootstrap and wanted a reusable solution with minimal code and css. Looks really good though! :)

Comment: @Aaron i assumed you were using bootstrap for because of the classname in your code. I have updated the snippet without linking it to bootstrap. bootstrap comes handy when you want to configure the responsive behaviors ... via specifics classes. You may reconsider it :)